# prevent hover effect before pointer is 3px inside the object

Tags: css

```
.btngo:hover{
    bottom:3px;
}
```

`btngo` goes up for `3px` when pointer is over, but if pointer is just on the edge of `btngo` it starts flickering, i.e. goes up and down very fast.

Is there a way to prevent this?

This effect should not start before pointer is `3px` inside of `btngo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a container on where you apply the hover effect and you avoid the flicker as this container will not move.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btngo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.container:hover .btngo {
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btngo">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because once the hover takes effect and the element moves, you are no longer hovering and so the hover no longer applies...and it loops.

A solution is to maintain the hover by giving the pointer something to hover over while the pointer is *apparently* no longer over the element.

This can be achieved by a pseudo-element positioned at the bottom of the element (since this *jitter* is only an issue when hovering from below)...and expand the height of the pseudo-element on parent hover.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:2em auto;
}

div::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:3px; /* your proposed bottom position value change */
  top:100%;
  background:transparent;
}

div:hover {
 bottom:3px; 
}

div:hover::before {
  height:6px; /* position value plus height */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

No additional HTML, pure CSS solution.